# How to show that $\inf f(I)>0$ for an interval $I$ and a function $f$ with the following property?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose that for an interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ there exists a number $M>0$ such that for all $x\in I$ the inequality $|f'(x)/f(x)|\leq M$ is satisfied. Then it is asked to show that $\inf f(I)>0$.

Now, if $I$ is a bounded interval, it is possible to prove the claim using the MVT.

However, I am unable to prove it if the interval $I$ is unbounded.
How should we proceed to show that $\inf f(I)>0$, whenever $I$ is unbounded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've misstated the conditions above, but $f(x)=e^{-x}$ with $I=(0,\infty)$, $M=1$, and $\inf f(I)=0$ should be a counterexample to your statement.

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong when $I$ is unbounded**

Take $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $I=(0,\infty)$.